# .Net Core and NTLM on OSX

Tags: macos, ntlm

I have a .Net Core application (it is a NUnit based integration test) with authorizes with a server using HttpClient. The Server uses NTLM for authentication.

When I run this test under Windows, it works fine.
When I run this test under OSX, it tells me that there are authentication errors.

When I watch the traffic using fiddler, I notice that the server response witha "401" and tells the client that it can authenticate using NTLM. Under OSX the reaction of HttpClient is to return with authentication error.

Is NTLM not supported for OSX? Can I fix  this somehow?

Comment: NTLM is not officially supported for OSX - it is a Microsoft proprietary protocol.  For SSO protocol to Active Directory use Kerberos.  But you're asking about NTLM, so, be aware that any NTLM modules that you see out there on the Internet are reversed-engineered versions of NTLM which may or may not work, or work to some degree but maybe not 100% of what you're looking for, depending on the OS platform.  For OSX, I see this here but I've never tested it:  https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/UWWI/Enabling+NTLMv2+on+Mac+OS-X

Comment: Also try this if you like the Firefox web browser on OSX:  https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/http_auth_handler_ntlm.h?view=markup&pathrev=10667

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I need to do this:

```
        var credential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
        var myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri(myURL), "NTLM", credential);

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        handler.Credentials = myCache;
```

Now it works under osx!

But it stopped working on windows :-).

I could do a "if" to determine if I am on osx or not ...

Maybe there is a better way to make this work on osx *and* windows?

Comment: Where did you find how to do that?  I'd like to bookmark it.

Comment: I really cannot find it anymore, otherwise I would have posted it. Here is a related link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/129030, but the solution is not exactly the same.